# Catch click on Navigate on the MapToolbar in a Google Maps FragmentActivity?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

[image: This button is what I mean]

I'm using Android Studio and I have created a Map Activity.  When I add markers to the map, and you click on them, you are presented with a popup overlay toolbar with a 'navigate to this marker' button and a 'show in Google Maps' button.  When the user clicks the 'navigate to this marker' button I want to be notified and be able to log that it happened.  How do I catch this event?

I've tried:

(googleMap).setOnMapClickListener(|EVENT|); - never fires
        (googleMap).setOnInfoWindowClickListener(|EVENT|); - never fires
        (googleMap).setOnMarkerClickListener(|EVENT|); - never fires

Is there a way to do this?  I don't even really need to interrupt the event, I just need to be notified that it's happening so I can record it.

Comment: For now, I have disabled the overlay toolbar and am catching the marker click in setOnMarkerClickListener.  This isn't perfect nor elegant, but it does get the job done.  I'm still interested in hearing any ideas if someone has them so I can use the Google way.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Google doesn't want to let us to catch the click event for the map toolbar.

You make your own map toolbar with two images, and then you can catch the event when you click it. So you can use code like this to achieve your aim:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=b");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```